# Don't allow numbers like 067 or 045 in textbox. Windows Phone application

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, textbox, numbers

I have a problem. I want my textbox to not accept non-existing numbers. I already made so my textbox don't accept decimal. But when i enter for example 0865, i want it to be converted immidietly into 865. I don't know how to do it. Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using System.Globalization;

namespace KeepThemTogether
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        int from_a, to_b, generatedNumber;

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void from_text(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void to_change(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void ShowGen()
        {
            ShGenTxt.Text = Convert.ToString(generatedNumber);
        }

        private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            from_a = Int32.Parse(FromTxt.Text);
            to_b = Int32.Parse(ToTxt.Text);        
            Random generate = new Random();
            generatedNumber = generate.Next(from_a, to_b);
            ShowGen();
        }

        private void from_up(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox txt = (TextBox)sender;
            if (txt.Text.Contains('.'))
            {
                txt.Text = txt.Text.Replace(".", "");
                txt.SelectionStart = txt.Text.Length;
            }
        }

        private void to_up(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox txt = (TextBox)sender;
            if (txt.Text.Contains('.'))
            {
                txt.Text = txt.Text.Replace(".", "");
                txt.SelectionStart = txt.Text.Length;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This link: http://www.atleyhunter.com/2010/11/12/making-textbox-numbers-only-for-windows-phone-7/ shows how to create numbers only. perhaps you can adapt to restrict numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to remove leading zeros you could use this to handle the TextChanged event

```
private void RemoveLeadingZeros(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox txt = (TextBox)sender;
    txt.Text = txt.Text.TrimStart('0');
}
```

Comment: Wow, that was unexpected to be that easy. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use regex and run it against the input with the method _TextChanged.

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch("[^0-9]", textBox1.Text))
     {
         MessageBox.Show("Please enter only numbers.");
         textBox1.Text.Remove(textBox1.Text.Length - 1);
     }
 }
```